# Как откатить изменение, если эти файлы перечисляются в .gitignore?

Tags: git

В .gitignore прописаны файлы, которые выходят после компиляции (*.o, *.lib, сама программа).
Как откатить компиляцию? (что б остались только исходники)

К примеру: репозиторий в исходном состоянии.

1. Делаю новую ветку **git branch modification; git checkout modification;**
2. компилирую **./autogen.sh; ./configure; make;**
3. перехожу в мастер, удаляю **git checkout master; git branch -d modification;**

файлы остались

Comment: Удалить руками. У вас билд не в отдельной папке происходит?

Comment: Нет, используется же automake.
Значит хака нет?

Comment: Вы хотите удалить все файлы прокме тех которые под контролем гит, верно?

Comment: хак есть, называется `make clean` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте `git clean`, см. [ссылку](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B)

> Команда git clean используется для удаления мусора из рабочей
>   директории. Это могут быть результаты сборки проекта или файлы
>   конфликтов слияний.

Comment: Точно, ну я и дурак, нужно было написать **git clean -ffxd**